# setgid bit in umask of systemd service script

Tags: linux, ubuntu, files, filesystems

I have a downloader service running, and I'd like it to set the setgid bit of every directory it creates. Its already doing so, but I suspect that's because at the moment, the parent directory also has setgid. What do I set the umask to?

I'm also wondering how umask, particularly in a systemd script, works for the "4th" digit. I understand that its inverted, so that umask = 002 is like chmod 775. But what about umask = 2002. Is that chmod 5775? or chmod 2775?

Thanks!

Comment: It should be `2775`!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe the octal numbers for:

- sticky bit is `1`,
- setgid on directories: `2`, and
- setuid on files: `4`.

So for the case your asking it would be: `umask 2002` ==> `2775` for folders.